# How to make onecolumn/twocolumn parts in a document class?

Tags: titles, two-column, documentclass-writing

I have a simple document class adapted from `article`, but independent (`.cls` file). The document is `twocolumn`, but when I add a title with

```
  \newcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
  \end{center}\par
  \end{titlepage}%
}
\newenvironment{titlepage}
    {%
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \setcounter{page}\@ne
    }%
```

This makes the entire document `onecolumn`. How should I set the `titlepage` environment to be `onecolumn` without affecting the entire document?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The definition of the `titlepage` environment in `article.cls` depends on whether compatibility mode is on/off, but both variants include

```
\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
```

in the code to be executed at the end of the environment. In your version of `titlepage`, you simply switch to `\onecolumn` (which makes `\@restonecoltrue` superfluous) at the start of the environment, so you need to switch back to `\twocolumn` at the end. I suggest, however, to simply use the original non-compatibility variant of `titlepage`, as this will make your custom class also work in `onecolumn` mode.

Comment: very clear information! I wonder how I missed that critical line :)

Answer (score 2):

You can define `\maketitle` using the optional argument to the command `\twocolumn`:

```
\def\maketitle{%
  \twocolumn[\vbox to \textheight{\vfil
    \begin{center}\LARGE \@title \par\end{center}%
  \vfil}]%
  \clearpage
}
```

The command `\twocolumn` does 3 things:

1. starts a new page if necessary
2. typesets its optional argument in one-column mode
3. the rest of the new page is in two-column mode